# All elements in custom UITableViewCell turn nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell called `GenericRouteTableViewCell`

```
@interface GenericRouteTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDirection;
```

I haven't done anything to the implementation file.

In my storyboard I have a regular UITableViewController, with 1 prototype cell.

- Class of that prototype cell: `GenericRouteTableViewCell`
- Reuse identifier of the prototype cell: `GenericRouteTableViewCell`
- I've hooked up the labels to the outlets, haven't hooked up the cell anywhere in particular
- I've set the cell height to 100

In the code of the UITableViewController

- In `viewDidLoad` I call
  `[self.tableView registerClass:[GenericRouteTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GenericRouteTableViewCell"];`
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I do:

  ```
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"GenericRouteTableViewCell";
  GenericRouteTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  [cell.lblDirection setText:@"test"];
  ```

The result:

I just get empty default cells, and when setting a breakpoint, the cell gets instantiated, I see my labels instantiated and before they are filled with values they are nilled.

What am I doing wrong?

Xcode 6.3, latest SDK

Comment: You shouldn't register a class for cell if you have it in Storyboard.

Comment: Left the line out, but did not seem to have any effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like you didn't add delegates for your tableView.
`UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: UITableViewCell's don't require these delegates I guess? Why would they ever need them?

Comment: @Martijn yes sure. But it's needed for UITableView.
The delegate of a UITableView object must adopt the UITableViewDelegate protocol. Optional methods of the protocol allow the delegate to manage selections, configure section headings and footers, help to delete and reorder cells, and perform other actions.The UITableViewDataSource protocol is adopted by an object that mediates the application’s data model for a UITableView object. The data source provides the table-view object with the information it needs to construct and modify a table view.

Comment: On second thought, seems like these delegates were left out, strange. Adding them now...

Comment: So be sure that you have @interface ClassName : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> in .h file. In viewDidLoad write _tableView.delegate = self; _tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: @Martijn is it helped you?

Comment: This did in fact help me... Strangely enough, Xcode isn't adding them automatically anymore